# Proper Use of Keep Alive For Loop

Tags: java, json, loops, http, keep-alive

I'm working to make a thread that monitors a web api to get the latest announcement via JSON. I cannot test this currently, so I'm unsure if anything needs to be changed with this. I've read through other questions but everyone else doesn't seem to be using a loop to keep getting a response.

```
public void run(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(announcementsURL);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("GET");
        http.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        http.setUseCaches(false);
        http.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        http.setConnectTimeout(10);
        http.setReadTimeout(10);
        while (true){
            http.connect();
            int status = http.getResponseCode();
            if (status == 201){
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                String json = sb.toString();
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject jsonResponse = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
                if (!(lastAnnouncement == (long) jsonResponse.get("time"))){
                    //String announcement = (String) jsonResponse.get("message");
                    //TODO What to do with announcement...
                }
            }
            http.getInputStream().close();
            http.disconnect();
        }

    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.interrupt();
        try {
            this.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try posting this in Code Review

Comment: Doesn't `http.disconnect()` defeat the keep-alive?

Comment: @200_success I thought I read somewhere that your supposed to do that? I can very well be wrong hence why I'm posting here.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I'll do that, thanks!